# Is vldr/vstr atomic?

Tags: arm, neon

Is arm's vldr/vstr atomic on smp?like one thread is doing

```
vldr d0, mem0
vstr d0, mem1
```

the other doing

```
vmov d0, r0,r1
vstr d0, mem0
```

so would thread one sees the consistent memory state with both r0 and r1 visible or not?

Comment: ARM ARM: *A3.5.3
Atomicity in the ARM architecture, Single-copy atomicity: LDM , LDC , LDC2 , LDRD , STM , STC , STC2 , STRD , PUSH , POP , RFE , SRS , VLDM , VLDR , VSTM , and VSTR instructions are executed as a
sequence of word-aligned word accesses. Each 32-bit word access is guaranteed to be single-copy atomic. The
architecture does not require subsequences of two or more word accesses from the sequence to be single-copy
atomic.*

Comment: thank you please chang your commet to answer